# mysql mariadb LIKE search that gets matching parents

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Given a data row structure such as

```
a <=
aa <=       
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aab <=    
aaba
aabaa
aabb <=
aabba <=
aabbb <=
```

is there an expression for mysql/mariadb to do a `LIKE` search that matches `aabb%` to get the following results (gets matching parents as well as children)

```
a
aa    
aab
aabb
aabba
aabbb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A substring match is vastly different than a superstring match (in terms of how the comparison works).

You can still accomplish what you want, however, with two tests and an or clause.

```
WHERE (column_name LIKE 'aabb%' OR INSTR('aabb', column_name) = 1)
```

Comment: Perhaps `INSTR('aabb', col) = 1` ?

Comment: Yep!  Good catch!

Comment: @StevenMoseley, WOW that is impressive and fast, thanks I would have never have joined those dots & thanks to `pilcrow` for the edit.